# Rewrite a sum with tensor operations

Tags: matrices, tensors

I have a square matrix $R$ and a (symmetric) covariance matrix $\Sigma$. In terms of matrix or tensor operations, is there a simple way to write the following sum?

$$ \dot\sigma_{ij}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \big(r_{ik}\sigma_{jk}+r_{jk}\sigma_{ik}\big) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of matrix multiplication, you can write your equations as

$$ \frac{d\Sigma}{dt} = R \Sigma + \Sigma R. $$